# PHP - get all declared resources (traits, classes, functions and constants) within a given script?

Tags: php, function, class, token, traits

I designed a PHP 5.5+ framework comprised of more than 750 different classes to make both web applications and websites.

I would like to, ideally, be able to reduce its size by producing a version of itself containing just the bare essential files and resources needed for a given project (whether it's a website or a web application).

What I want to do is to be able to:

- reduce the amount of traits, classes, constants and functions to the bare essential per project
- compress the code files to achieve a lesser deployment size and faster execution (if possible)

So far, I've got the second part completed. But the most important part is the first, and that's where I'm having problems. I have a function making use of `get_declared_classes()` and `get_declared_traits()`, `get_defined_constants()` and `get_defined_functions()` to get the full list of user-defined classes, traits, functions and constants. But it gives me pretty much *EVERYTHING* and that's not what I want.

Is there a way to get all defined classes, functions and constants (no need for traits as I could run `class_uses()` on every class and get the list of traits in use by that class) for a single given script?

I know there's the `token_get_all()` function but I tried it with no luck (or maybe it's I'm using it the wrong way).

Any hint? Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Even if you got that, you'd also need to trace the internal dependencies inside your framework then. So, some script uses classes A, B and C of your framework. A depends on classes D and E, which in turn depend on F, G and H etc. etc. And since dependencies may not be obvious (e.g. `new $class` - can't trace that), it's hard to trace all that unless you have really good annotations that help you. Bottom line, this will probably be very hard, unless your framework is set up for this. In that case, I'd favour breaking the framework into more independent modules to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [PHP Parser](https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser/) for this. It constructs abstract syntax trees based on the files you supply to it. Then you can analyze its output for each file, and produce a report usable to you.

Other than that, you can use `token_get_all()` approach you've mentioned already, and write a small parser yourself. Depending on your project, this might be easier or more difficult. For example, do you use a lot of `new X()` constructs, or do you tend to pass dependencies via constructors?

Unfortunately, these are about the only viable choices you have, since PHP is dynamically typed language.

---

If you use dependency injection, however, you might want to take a look at your DI framework's internal cache files, which often contain such dependency maps. If you don't use such framework, I recommend to start doing this, especially since your project is big and that's where dependency injection excels at. [PHP-DI](http://php-di.org/), one of such frameworks, proved to be successful in some of my middle-size projects (25k SLOC).

Who knows? Maybe refactoring your project to use DI will let you accomplish the task you want without even getting to know all the dependencies. One thing I'm sure of is that it will help you maintain it.